# Opened tcp/8443 port does not show up in firewall-cmd in CentOS 8?

Tags: command-line, centos, firewall

I opened port 8443 in CentOS 8 using `firewall-cmd` like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp
```

But while that command runs successfully, it does not show up in the list of open ports when I run `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all`. What is going on here, and is the port actually open or not?

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno1
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ftp http https samba ssh telnet
  ports: 3389/tcp 23/tcp 9090/tcp 9091/tcp 9000/tcp 5222/tcp 4443/tcp 10000/udp 5443/tcp 8888/tcp 3000/tcp 1443/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Answer (score 2):

### You did not reload FirewallD after adding the rule.

#### You added the command correctly, but you need to reload FirewallD for it to pick up the new rule.

I tested this out on CentOS 8 as loaded within a Vagrant VirtualBox VM on my MacBook. When I initially logged into the VM right after it was built I enabled FirewallD and ran this command:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --list-all
```

And this is the output I got; note the ports area is blank:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Then I ran the exact command you used like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8443/tcp
```

Checking `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` showed the same exact output as above. Then I reloaded the FirewallD rules like this:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

The checked `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` again and port 8443 was listed as desired:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 8443/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```